# Cannot get data from BigQuery tables in north east asia via ODBC

Tags: google-bigquery, odbc

I want to get data from BigQuery tables via ODBC (Simba).

I configured ODBC data source and connected to tables, but couldn't get data from  tables only in specific region(US and EU is connected, but asia-northeast1 and asia-east1 is not).

I tried this using Excel but, same result when I used other tools.
Is this a problem only for tables in a specific region?

Environment

・Windows 10

・SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery32_2.1.11.1011

・Office 2013 Excel

Error Message

> DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Simba][BigQuery] (100) Error
>   interacting with REST API: Not found: Job [JobID] 詳細:
>       DataSourceKind=Odbc
>       DataSourcePath=dsn=[DSN]
>       OdbcErrors=Table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of the driver are you using?

Per Simba documentation this featue was released in version 2.1.17 at 2018-09-13

> Enhancements & New Features
>
> - [GAUSS-677] Support for querying datasets hosted in specific geographic 
>     locations
>
>   You can now query datasets that are hosted in specific geographic 
>     locations. For more information, see the Google BigQuery documentation 
>     on "Dataset Locations": 
>     https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-locations

You can download the latest version from this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/partners/simba-drivers/)

Please see your version in the ODBC window

[image]

In the advanced options, you can define the projects you are using and in the query wizard select the dataset from the right location

Comment: @shino note: important on SO - you can mark accepted answer by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. See [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235) for why it is important!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answering!

I used version 2.1.11 as I wrote above.
I could get data from tables in asia-northeast1 after installing latest version(2.1.20)!

Japanese Google official page about Simba driver is old and it linked old version(2.1.11) as latest.I specified the URL directly and got the latest.